# Regular expression without repeating numbers

Tags: regex, plsql

Can you help me to find out how I can build some regular expression to detect a valid sequence of numbers of 13 digits

first case:

```
1111111111111 -invalid
2222222222222 -invalid
333.....      -invalid
```

and same for the other digits, for this case I made this regex:

```
(^0+$)|(^1+$)|(^2+$)|(^3+$)|(^4+$)|(^5+$)|(^6+$)|(^7+$)|(^8+$)|(^9+$)
```

but I want to get this regex simplified, if there is a shorter way to get this validation.

second case:

```
9875978545111  - valid: only 3 1's  
11118578954547 - valid: only 4 1's
85781111954547 - valid: only 4 1's
9875978111111  - invalid: 6 1's
1111119875978  - invalid: 6 1's
9871111115978  - invalid: 6 1's
```

If there is a sequence of digits that repeats at least 6 times must be invalid,
like the last case if there is a way to make it shorter

I have this regex: `([0-9]+1{6,}+)|(^1{6,}+[0-9]+)`

case 3:

```
1212121212121
0101010101010
1231231231231
```

Pattern like theses must be invalid.

I have no idea how to write this regex.

Comment: I think you should give your exact validation rules. So, we will help you to build a good regex for its

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/vynpX9/1)?

Comment: Try  `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(col, '([0-9]+)\1{5}')`.

Comment: What makes case 3 valid or invalid? Number of different digits? Repeated sequences? Please elaborate.

Comment: A repeated sequence of digits as 12, 10, 123, etc.

Comment: Actually, `1231231231231` is not clear. The rest is clear: `NOT REGEX_LIKE(col, '^([0-9])\1+$|([0-9]+)\2{5}')`

Comment: Is `1213141516171` valid or invalid?

Comment: Thanks for everyone who took a minute to make a answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First case

For 13 repeated digits you can use: `^(\d)\1{12}$`, to match the lines with **valid** sequences. Therefore, just accept the lines where the regex **do match** anything. Live link for the example: https://regex101.com/r/4zi3ZZ/2

---

#### Second case

For more than 5 digits you can use: `(\d)\1{5}`, to match the lines with **invalid** sequences. Therefore, just accept the lines where the regex **do not match** anything. Live link for the example: https://regex101.com/r/vhoBCq/1

---

#### Third case

For the pattern search, you cannot do this with *regex*, because *regex* is to search patterns you know they exist. It cannot be used to extract patterns and research the string for the pattern it extracted. *Regular Expressions* are one of many [Formal Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) out there. It cannot do every thing as it is limited. However, everything you cannot do with *regex*, you can do through programming.

So, you need to write a program for pattern search. Once you know what is the pattern, you can use: `^(pattern)\1+$`, to match the lines with **valid** sequences. Therefore, just accept the lines where the regex **do match** anything. Live link for the example `^(123)\1+$` https://regex101.com/r/TCS46x/3

Answer (score 2):

Since [plsql](/questions/tagged/plsql) doesn't seams to support lookahead, you can use this regex `(\d)\1{5,}` and negate the match.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1 - 13 of same digit:

```
(\d)\1{12}
```

Case 2 - more than 5 of same digit (you must negate the result):

```
(\d)\1{5}
```

Case 3 - TBA

Answer (score 2):

Cases one and two:  repeating digits. This captures a digit and a repeat of that digit. The number in brackets defines the minimum length you want to match.

```
([0-9])\1{13}
([0-9])\1{6}
```

Case three: match a repeating sequence. Assuming you are still working with 13-digit numbers, the longest repeatable sequence would have 6 digits. This matches a repeating sequence of length 2-6.

```
([0-9]{2,6})\1
```

All cases require negation (positive match means invalid sequence).

Comment: Did you mean: All the lines with possible matches are invalid?

Comment: Yes. If I'm understanding the question correctly, finding the patterns means the number is not valid.